# Graphing atop logs

Tags: linux, debian, performance-monitor

I just discovered 'atop'. This is a fantastic tool for identifying performance bottlenecks in Linux. It supports a long term monitoring mode, in which it logs data to a binary log.

I would like to be able to visualize these data in a graph. Is this possible? If so, how?

I cannot seem to find out what format the log is saved in. It is binary, but nothing that 'file' will detect.

Comment: +1  `atopsar` (which comes with atop) is a half-way there. It displays any wanted metric vs time.  What remains is just to plot these time series.  A general solution to this with a web interface would be cool to have.  The accepted answer while great, doesn't go all the way towards a full solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A shell script to plot the three CPL load average fields from a list of atop log files.

```
#!/bin/sh -u
#   $0 [list of atop logfiles to plot]
# Plot the three CPL load average numbers from a list of atop log files.
# Uses a default atop log file if no arguments given.
# -Ian! D. Allen - idallen@idallen.ca - www.idallen.com

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    set -- '/var/log/atop.log'
fi

tmp=/tmp/atop$$
rm -f $tmp
trap "rm -f $tmp" 0 1 2

title=''
for log do
    if [ ! -s "$log" -o ! -r "$log" ] ; then
        echo 1>&2 "$0: $log: empty or unreadable - skipping"
        continue
    fi
    atop -PCPL -r "$log" >>$tmp || exit $?
    title="$title ${log##*/}"
done
if [ ! -s "$tmp" ] ; then
    echo 1>&2 "$0: No files plotted"
    exit 1
fi

len=${#title}
if [ $len -le 80 ] ; then
    title="Three CPL load averages from atop -PCPL\n$title"
else
    title="Three CPL load averages from atop -PCPL\n$(printf "%.77s..." "$title")"
fi

gnuplot -persist <<EOF

set xdata time 
set timefmt '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' 
set format x "%Y\n%m/%d\n%H:%M" 
set grid
set title noenhanced
set title "$title"
plot \
   "$tmp" using 4:8 notitle 'L1+' with points lc rgbcolor 'blue', \
   "$tmp" using 4:8 title 'L1+' smooth csplines lc rgbcolor 'blue', \
   "$tmp" using 4:9 notitle 'L2*' with points lc rgbcolor 'green', \
   "$tmp" using 4:9 title 'L2*' smooth csplines lc rgbcolor 'green', \
   "$tmp" using 4:10 notitle 'L3x'with points lc rgbcolor 'red', \
   "$tmp" using 4:10 title 'L3x' smooth csplines lc rgbcolor 'red', \
   ;

EOF
```

Comment: I have just tried this, but nothing happened. I ran
./plot-atop.sh /var/log/atop/atop_20140225

And it just returned. No plot was shown.

I tried with -x and the trace is as follows:


    + log=/var/log/atop/atop_20140225
    + tmp=/tmp/atop24693
    + rm -f /tmp/atop24693
    + trap rm -f /tmp/atop24693 0 1 2
    + atop -PCPL -r /var/log/atop/atop_20140225
    + gnuplot -persist
    + rm -f /tmp/atop24693

Comment: Try these: `wc /var/log/atop.log` and `echo $DISPLAY` and `atop -PCPL -r /var/log/atop.log | wc`

Comment: ~ $ wc /var/log/atop.log
wc: /var/log/atop.log: No such file or directory
~ $ wc /var/log/atop/atop_20140120
 10687   51924 2834046 /var/log/atop/atop_20140120
~ $ echo $DISPLAY
:0

Full properly formatted output here: http://paste.yt/p2863.html

How do I format code in a comment?

Comment: You need to give my script an `atop` log file that exists and is not empty.  You click on the **help** button to learn how to format.

Comment: Yeah, I am supplying an atop log file that exists and is not empty. I think that follows from the output above. If you are only seing the No such file or directory, then please note that this is for /var/log/atop.log. However, this is not the actual log file I am trying to use. Atop does not log in atop.log by default on debian based systems. It create a file per day. If you see the wc command above, you can see that it is indeed full of data. You can also see from my trace further above, that it is actually one of the date-files that I use for your script.

Comment: Does gnuplot work?  Try this: `echo "plot sin(x)" | gnuplot -persist`

Comment: I tried this. Nothing seems to happen. The command terminates right away. No gnuplot window is shown.

Comment: Then the problem isn't my script; it's your gnuplot.  Get that working first.

Comment: Output from gnuplot as well as the above command: http://paste.yt/p2886.html

Any ideas on how to fix gnuplot?   This is Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: When you fix `gnuplot`, try my script again and see if it answers this question.  Getting `gnuplot` working is a different question.

Comment: Tried on another machine. It works.

Comment: @IanD.Allen,how to read all log files.not only one day

Comment: @kittygirl I updated the script to plot more than one log file, e.g.  `./plot.sh /var/log/atop/atop_2019031[456]`

Comment: @IanD.Allen,tested it.Please have a look of  [![my screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/4dv1Fh4G/Untitled.png)],what's the meaning of 
 the green,blue,red lines?what's the meaning of `+`,`*`?

Comment: @kittygirl I updated the script to label the three plot lines.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor remote system usage, you could use a tool that outputs graphs to the terminal, like [atopsar-plot](https://codeberg.org/mgellner/atopsar-plot). It is capable of plotting historic days with the --day parameter. Installation is easy, you just need [atop](https://www.atoptool.nl/downloadatop.php), Python and pip. No configuration neccessary.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of atopsar-plot.

```
$ atopsar-plot --day 0 --disk sda --iface 0s31f6

                       %CPU_idle                  
      ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
1586.0┤▄▄▄█████▄▄▄▖       ▖   ▐█▄▄▄▄▄▄█▟█▙▄▄▄▄▄▄▄│
1532.0┤████████████▙▄▄▄▄▄▟█▖  ▟██████████████████│
1478.0┤█████████████████████▖▗███████████████████│
1424.0┤█████████████████████▙████████████████████│
      └┬────────┬────────┬──────────┬───────────┬┘
       09:57  10:37    11:07      12:07     13:07 

                      %DSK_busy                   
    ┌────────────────────────────────────────────┐
36.0┤                      ▟▄                    │
24.0┤                     ▟██▌                   │
12.0┤▄▄                  ▗████                   │
 0.0┤█████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▟█▄█████████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄│
    └┬────────┬────────┬──────┬──────┬──────────┬┘
     09:57  10:27    11:07  11:57  12:17    13:07 

                      MB_SWP_free                 
      ┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
8192.0┤████████████████████▙▄▄                   │
8186.7┤███████████████████████▙▖                 │
8181.3┤██████████████████████████▄▄              │
8176.0┤█████████████████████████████▙▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄│
      └┬────────┬────────┬──────────┬───────────┬┘
       09:57  10:37    11:07      12:07     13:07 

                      NET_iMbps                   
    ┌────────────────────────────────────────────┐
73.0┤                     ▄█                     │
48.7┤                    ▗██▖                    │
24.3┤                    ▐██▌                    │
 0.0┤▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█████████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄│
    └┬────────┬────────┬──────┬──────┬──────────┬┘
     09:57  10:27    11:07  11:57  12:17    13:07 

                      NET_oMbps                   
     ┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐
151.0┤                             ▗▟            │
100.7┤                           ▗▟██▖           │
 50.3┤                          ▄████▌           │
  0.0┤▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄███████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄│
     └┬─────────┬───────┬───────────┬───────────┬┘
      09:57   10:37   11:07       12:07     13:07
```

Comment: That's awesome... but where does the data come from? How do I specify the log file created by atop?

Comment: This shouldn't be neccessary since atopsar-plot parses atopsar log output directly. Just specify the --day parameter and you are fine.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I guess what I was missing is that once `atop` is installed, it starts running continuously in the background. So the logs are always there (no need to create them manually) in `/var/log/atop/...`

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I create a service that solves this problem.

It accepts atop files as input and converts them to the influxdb database format, after which the graphs are available in grafana. All this is on https://atopgraph.info

To use the service, you need to click the "Get Started" button and then upload your atop files with browser or curl.

Answer (score 0):

The man pages (`man atop`) provide good information on how to look at the raw log files. Atop itself provides viewing facilities, with the option of generating "parseable output" which you could then use to generate a visualisation. So, just look at `man atop` and search for this term by entering: `\PARSEABLE OUTPUT`

Comment: You search in `man` pages using `/PARSEABLE` not `\PARSEABLE` -- see the `man` page for the `less` program or use the `h` or `?` key to bring up the HELP screen while viewing the `man` page itself.